# Need assistance regarding understanding autolayouts

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I am trying to get my head around auto layouts so I am following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2) but I am not getting this formula `The width of the green view is calculated by the formula “width of superview minus (98 + 62)”` my constraints values are `(46 + 82)` and when I apply this formula I am not getting the correct values, I also created a uiview with size 160x284.

I am not getting correct values but still Xcode not complaining and very thing is working fine, why? I also created a outlet and NSLog the values but they are different.

This auto layout seems very confusing :(

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don´t need to set a constraint for the width. It will be  calculated by XCODE if you have set the trailing (left margin) and leading space (right margin) constraints. XCode will complain if you set Trailing, Leading and Width constraints for the same view.